# HSTS: Clicking through certificate errors

Tags: hsts

We have a website www.example.com with a certificate for domain www.example.com, we also have HSTS enabled. The Qualys SSL Labs (https://www.ssllabs.com/index.html) confirmed that HSTS has been enabled.

I noticed that if you go to https://test.example.com (which is served by the same Web Server), you encounter a certificate error, which is to be expected, as there is no certificate for test.example.com loaded on the Web Server. However, I have noticed that you can click through the certificate errors, and the web content is then served.

To me this is unexpected behavior. I thought that one of the central ideas behind HSTS is that you cannot click through certificate errors. From Wikipedia: "If the security of the connection cannot be ensured (e.g. the server's TLS certificate is not trusted), show an error message and do not allow the user to access the web application".

This happened with both Firefox 59.0.2 (32-bit) and Chrome (65.0.3325.146 (64-bit)).

My question: Why would a browser allow a user to click through certificate errors on a website where HSTS is enabled?

Comment: Does `https://test.example.com/` send a HSTS header?

Comment: @Arminius: It sure does. From the Developer Tools: strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your browser doesn't apply the HSTS policy of `test.example.com` because it hasn't seen the header before over error-free secure transport. Therefore, it still allows you to "add an exception".

> The user agent processing model [...] stipulates that a host is initially noted as a
> Known HSTS Host, or that updates are made to a Known HSTS Host's
> cached information, **only if the UA receives the STS header field over
> a secure transport connection having no underlying secure transport
> errors or warnings.**

[(From RFC 6796, emphasis my own)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6797#section-14.3)

Seeing the header over plain HTTP or with certificate warnings doesn't count:

> The `Strict-Transport-Security` header is **ignored** by the browser when your site is accessed using HTTP; this is because an attacker may intercept HTTP connections and inject the header or remove it.  When your site is accessed over HTTPS with no certificate errors, the browser knows your site is HTTPS capable and will honor the `Strict-Transport-Security` header.

[(From MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Strict-Transport-Security)

Also, note that your `includeSubDomains` directive from `www.example.com` doesn't apply since `test.example.com` isn't a direct subdomain (doesn't match `*.www.example.com`).

Comment: however, as he said in another comment, he's adding the subdomains. `strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains` so your assumption is not valid

Comment: @yzT `test.example.com` is not a subdomain of `www.example.com`.

Comment: yeah sorry, I missed that part. I read just `example.com` :P

Comment: @Arminius: So the implication of what you are saying is that "https with certificate errors" is the same as http (at least as far as HSTS is concerned). Makes sense, thanks for the feedback, I have some food for thought regarding the ramifications of this.

Comment: @Jakkals Curiously, the RFC has a section [Ramifications of HSTS Policy Establishment Only over Error-Free
       Secure Transport](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6797#section-14.3) which you may find helpful.

Comment: @Arminius never new that man. presumably if this was `example.com` then subdomain would be `test.example.com`